# Jquery IndexOf finding numbers after $ symbol

Tags: jquery

```
 if($('form').html().indexOf('VPS', 0) > -1) {
console.log("Found");
     }

} else {
console.log("Not found");
}
```

Hi, above is my code that i have right now, what I am trying to do is find the word "VPS" in the form and if it finds the word "VPS" it should also find this "$" symbol in the form and give me the numbers that are after the "$" symbol

So what the script would have done is, Find the word "VPS" if it finds it get the numbers that are after the "$" sign, how should I do that?

```
<form method='post'>
  <input type='hidden' name='ID' value=321 />
  <b>[2014-10-13 00:01:28]</b> 
  xJMC is selling 1 VPS Server(s) for $200. 
  <input style='float:right;' value='BUY NOW' name='bootBtn' type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-mini' />
  <br>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have just one form?

Comment: No there is several forms in the HTML but I gave you one just to make it easier, I can post all forms if you want.

Comment: I rather take the easy answer than no answer

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/zu3p6gmb/

Comment: @undefined, why don't you write that regex example as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.match()` method to capture the price as intended. Since you have mentioned that multiple forms are possible, I would recommend looping through all instances of the `<form>` element. The prices are captured with the `price` object generated by `.match()`.

```
$('form').each(function() {
    if($(this).html().indexOf('VPS', 0) > -1) {
        var price = $(this).text().match(/(\$\d+(\.\d+)?)/);
        console.log(price[0]);
    }
});
```

The trick is to capture prices with the pattern `/(\$\d+(\.\d+)?)/`. It means that the prices must be followed by a `$` sign, and followed by one or more digits, and optionally followed by the radix (`.`) and denominator (cents).

[See working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/eh62L4t6/) (check the browser's console log to see the captured price).